# Bitwise where condition check in mybatis

Tags: mysql, mybatis

How to check a bitwise where the condition is?

The following table shows three columns.
3rd Colun 'Col' takes an integer value.
I want to check for Colvalue 4.
`ColValue = 4; tableName`

```
Col1        | Col2      | Col
Data1Col1   |Data1Col2  |  1
Data2Col1   |Data2Col2  |  1
Data1Col1   |Data3Col2  |  6
Data4Col1   |Data4Col2  |  6
Data5Col1   |Data5Col2  |  6
Data6Col1   |Data6Col2  |  4
Data7Col1   |Data7Col2  |  4
Data8Col1   |Data8Col2  |  2
```

```
SELECT * from tableName where Col = #{ColValue};
```

Input for ColValue is 4 which satisfies both 4 And 6 for & bitwise.

Expected Result:

```
Data1Col1   |Data3Col2  |  6
Data4Col1   |Data4Col2  |  6
Data5Col1   |Data5Col2  |  6
Data6Col1   |Data6Col2  |  4
Data7Col1   |Data7Col2  |  4
```

Comment: You must use birwise AND `&` operator: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE col & 4`. If the bit present, then `&` gives the result = 4 which is treated as TRUE, else the result = 0 which is treated as FALSE.

Comment: 'SELECT * from tableName where Col amp #{ColValue} = #{ColValue}';
is also not working.

Comment: It is excess compare operation, and no profit. And so yes, works.